# Keyboard not working on login screen MacBook Pro

Tags: keyboard, login, login-screen

I have a MacBook Pro with OSx 10.11.6 installed.

On startup, when I try to login as a user with password, each time I click on the input text box it gets deselected, and it's impossible to enter the password.

However, if I enter as Guest, the keyboard works perfectly on Safari and all applications. So I really have no idea what's going on.

For now, I set the auto-login on startup without password, so I don't have to type anything in the login screen. But that's just a workaround, since I really need to enable the password.

Hope someone knows how to solve this.

Ps: I can get to type a letter or two if I click on the input box and type really fast, but still. And this happens for ALL characters.

Comment: Did you try, safe boot, smc and pram reset? What was your results?